# Retrieving data from form inputs

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm trying to retrieve data from form inputs created using symfony

Here is my FormUploaderType:

```
class FormUploaderType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('service', ChoiceType::class, [
                'placeholder'   => 'Wybierz serwis',
                'choices'       => [
                    'home'      => 'home',
                    'az'        => 'az',
                    'ionos.bg'  => 'ionosbg',
                    'ionos.ro'  => 'ionosro',
                    'ionos.hu'  => 'ionoshu',
                    ],
                'mapped'        => false,
            ])
            ->add('date', DateType::class)
            ->add('terms', FileType::class)
            ->add('button', SubmitType::class);
    }
```

And here how my form is looking in html:

[image]

I'm trying to get the data from form_uploader_date inputs, but this line of code:

```
$date = $form->get('form_uploader')->getData();
```

or:

```
$date = $form->get('form_uploader[date]')->getData();
```

doesnt' seem to work... I don't what to do...

Comment: Did you try $date = $form->getData()['date'];? By the way it better to have a DTO in the form and access the data over said DTO https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony-forms/form-dto

Answer (score 2):

Did you handle request? You shoud do something like this:

```
$form = $this->createForm(CLASS);
$form->handleRequest($request);` // you should inject Request from HttpFoundation namespace
```

After that, validate if your request is `POST` like this:

```
if($form->isSubmitted() & $form->isValid()) {
    $data = $form->getData(); 
// This array holds all your data. 
// Use this instead of accesing each element as $form->get('property-name')->getData();
}
```

Note: If your form class is associated with an entity/model, then that form will be mapped on that class. Otherwise, it will be just an array. You don't need to access it that way. Moreover, you can use `dump()` or `dd()` (for Symfony 4.x +) functions to dump your content using a pretty format.

Comment: Thank you, this one helped! :)